# The way to pass system environment variables to child process in java

Tags: java, system, environment

I want to create child process in JAVA, and I wantthis process to have parent's env variables and some new envariables all.

In my knowledge, If I use Runtime.exec(cmd, null), then child process just inherits parent's env.
And If I user Runtime.exec(cmd, new String[]), then child process has only env that I assigend.

But I want my child process to have parent's env and new env variables all...

So, I thought this java code is the only way to achieve my goal...

```
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        String[] envp = new String[100];
        int idx = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : env.entrySet()) {
            String envKey = entry.getKey();
            String envValue = entry.getValue();
            envp[idx++] = envKey + "=" + envValue;
        }
        String cmd = "my java command array for child process...";
        String newEnv = key + "=" + value;
        envp[idx] = newEnv;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec(cmd, envp);
```

Is any another better way? or is this code not good?

This is my first asking and sorry if this asking is difficult to understand because my english skill is very bad...

Thank you

I searched many posts and one way I found was like this...

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
Field field = env.getClass().getDeclaredField("m");
field.setAccessible(true);
((Map<String, String>) field.get(env)).put(name, val);
```

But I don't like to modify unmodifiable Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is any another better way?

I would do it with `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime`. It has more configurable options and you can add your environment variables to a map instead of building a String. You can even manipulate the inherited variables. Like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind example! It's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here a concise summary of the alternative approach using ProcessBuilder-

Instead of using `Runtime.exec(cmd, envp)`, you can use `ProcessBuilder` to execute
the child process with both the parent's environment variables and additional
environment variables:

```java
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("my", "java", "command", "array", "for", "child", "process");
Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
environment.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
environment.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

With `ProcessBuilder`, you construct the command and arguments for the child process.
The `environment()` method retrieves the environment variable map, which initially
contains the parent's environment. You can then add additional environment
variables using the `put()` method. Finally, calling `start()` executes the
child process with the combined environment variables.

Using `ProcessBuilder` offers more flexibility and control over process execution
compared to `Runtime.exec()`, allowing you to manage input/output streams and error
handling more easily.